# jQuery transitions or CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-transitions

Should I use CSS transitions or jQuery?

I've seen some jQuery plugins use both with jQuery only being used if the browser does not support the CSS transition.

How is this done?

Comment: You should not do user agent sniffing, see my answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do JQuery transitions and CSS transitions with JQuery.

You could run a check on the user's browser and do something like this

```
var thing = $('#something');
var browserIsIE = function() {
    return false;
}

if ( browserIsIE() ) {
    thing.fadeOut();
}
else {
    thing.addClass('hidden');
}
```

CSS:

```
#something{
   transition: opacity 0.4s;
}

.hidden {
    opacity: none;
}
```

Note that this code doesn't actually check the browser version, but it handles how to fade the element, you should create a function to check whatever you need to check!

Answer (score 0):

The plugins are probably checking the browser version.
[Take a look here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) for an overview of the browsers supporting CSS's transition.

Answer (score 0):

If you are pretty much confirmed that your user will be using the latest version of chrome or Mozilla or any other (IE not counted) then `CSS` can also be considered as a option. or else you can also user version of `JQuery` which also gives support for IE. and best combination is using both for a website will be giving a better result.

Answer (score 0):

**[Never ever use User Agent sniffing](http://www.sitepoint.com/why-browser-sniffing-stinks/)**, rather use feature support/ detection. That is what god gave us [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) for.

Modernizr adds CSS classes to your html depending on which technologies the viewing browser supports. In your CSS you can then write:

```
.csstransitions #myelement { /* do css3 stuff */ }
```

and in jQuery:

```
if (!$('html').hasClass('csstransitions')) { /* jQuery fallback */ }
```